# Cache text from UITextField

Tags: iphone, caching, uitextfield

Hello
I have an app with a textfield that user have to enter his email.
Is there any way to cache the emails that have been inserted to this textfield?
I want an autocomplete of the email when the user enter the email. If this is not possible I want at least the app save the last email that the user has used. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to store the email value:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standarduserdefaults] setValue:@"user@domain.com" forKey:@"Email"];
```

To Read it back use:

```
NSString *sEmail = [[NSUserDefaults standarduserdefaults] stringForKey:@"Email"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the data by using [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - save it when the user has finished entering the e-mail address, then restore it again when the view is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store large number of emails means you have to use the property list... In NSUserDefaults you have to store only the important values

[Property list](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html)